# Spring boot with security default login successful redirection issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on spring boot with security, I want to have custom login page and after successful login ,i want to open dashboard page.
In my code I have used default login page after successful login , it is not redirected to dashboard page.
I have tried multiple ways,but no luck.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)
//            .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .permitAll();
}
}
```

WebMvcConfigurer

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.hrmanagement")
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

//    registry.addViewController("/loginPage").setViewName("login");
      registry.addViewController("/dashboard").setViewName("login");
//    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
}
```

[image] 
  after successful login, it is redirected to http://localhost:8080/dashboard

I get
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Mar 10 17:14:47 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available.

I tried, adding login page in multiple locations(static,templates folders then added webapp-views) but no luck, can any one please suggest or help me in better understanding.

Comment: Could you enable the debug and share us the [complete log](https://gist.github.com/) (be careful with sensitive data)? Also, just to try, could you create a simple [@RestController](https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates/blob/master/001-no-database/src/main/java/com/springwalk/sample/controller/CustomerController.java) with /test_redirect and use it instead your **/dashboard**?

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz My Log : https://justpaste.it/5613g  , if i create a simple RestController with /test_redirect, it is going to html page (in template). But after successful login, it should go to /test_redirect